# Running Selenium IDE tests via Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

I should start off by saying that I am regretfully and painfully a **noob**. But I'm trying to change that!! I do not know any programming languages, but have managed to "make things happen" by doing enough research to get whatever job I've ever needed done done.

Anyway, I have been creating Selenium tests using the Selenium IDE and I am having a bit of trouble getting these test to run via Selenium Grid.

I have been exporting the tests as JUnit 4 (Webdriver) files. I am running the grid on a Ubuntu headless server, and my remote controls on one Windows 7 machine running IE9 and Firefox, and a Windows Vista machine running IE8 and Chrome.

My goal is to take the tests that I've exported from Selenium IDE as JUnit 4 (Webdriver) files and run them from the grid in parallel on my two Windows machines. I have edited my hosts files on my Windows machines to recognize the Ubuntu server by the name of "seleniumgrid". For example:

**On the Ubuntu server terminal 1:**
ant launch-hub

**Win7 terminal1:**
ant -Dport=5555 -Denvironment="IE9 on Windows" -Dhost=Win7 -DhubURL=http://seleniumgrid:4444 launch-remote-control

**Win7 terminal2:**
ant -Dport=5555 -Denvironment="Firefox on Windows" -Dhost=Win7 -DhubURL=http://seleniumgrid:4444 launch-remote-control

**Vista termina1:** 
ant -Dport=5555 -Denvironment="IE8 on Windows" -Dhost=WinVista -DhubURL=http://seleniumgrid:4444 launch-remote-control

**Vista terminal2:** 
ant -Dport=5555 -Denvironment="Chrome on Windows" -Dhost=WinVista -DhubURL=http://seleniumgrid:4444 launch-remote-control

Now, from here, I'm trying to launch the JUnit4 (webdriver) file that I have exported from Selenium IDE to run this configuration. The name of the file is titled : Registration.java.

What do I have to do now to run the Registration.jar file? I can't seem to find any documentation that answers this question, which leads me to believe that I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how this all works...

Pardon if this question has been answered before. I have poor terminology when it comes to this stuff.

HUGE thanks for taking the time to read this, and even more for an answer if there is one.

-brandon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to launch hub and nodes via ant. You can run them from cmd:

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -role hub` -- will run hub
`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -role node -hub http://seleniumgrid:4444/grid/register` -- will run node

Default port for node is 5555, so for the second terminal you should specify port that differs from default one, e.g. 5556:

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -role node -port 5556 -hub http://seleniumgrid:4444/grid/register`

Also you should specify browser parameters for each node, e.g.:

`-browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=5,platform=WINDOWS`

In your JUnit tests you should use `RemoteWebDriver` with `DesiredCapabilities`:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

For parallel execution you should edit your tests additionally (sorry, don't work with jUnit, so can't help here much except of link that you can find below.)

Include JUnit class files, your class files, including your JUnit test classes, libraries your class files depend on in your classpath on Linux machine:

```
export CLASSPATH=$JUNIT_HOME/junit.jar:/myproject/classes:/myproject/lib/something.jar
```

Invoke the Junit command on Linux machine:

```
 java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore [test class name]
```

Or you can use `ant` instead.

I will recommend to start with hub on Linux and one node with one browser on Windows without any parallelization, so you will be sure that this part works correctly. As a next step run tests for two nodes sequentially and then try to run them in parallel.

For complete tutorials read these materials: [How do I run JUnit using Ant](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#running_5), [Activating Junit tests from Command Line](http://www.jsystemtest.org/?q=node/44), [Grid2 tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2), [Parallel JUnit 4 and Selenium](http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2010/10/parallel-junit-4-and-selenium-part-one-parameters/) (three parts)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Aleh! Appreciate you taking the time.

I've heard that there are some troubles with JUnit when deploying parallel tests, and have been told that TestNG are actually much better suited for this task. Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Comment: @btdeviant, yes I agreed. I saw TestNG solutions somewhere on StackOverflow and around the Internet when I did my investigation for running tests in parallel with NUnit, but didn't encounter with good jUnit ones.

Comment: @btdeviant as far as I remember, old version of selenium grid should contain some kind of demo of parallel tests execution based on TestNG

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for that. I'll be looking into TestNG then. Standby for some more "noob" questions!! 

Thank you again sir :D

Comment: Okay. I've got grid 2 up and running. I'm still wondering how it is that I run the tests that I've exported from Selenium IDE to run on the grid. Lets say the file that I've exported as a TestNG from Selenium IDE has the title: Registration.java.

I fire up the hub on my linux machine, a node on my windows machine. Now what? How to I actually run the test? Do I have to modify / create an .xml file? I'm stuck :( Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @btdeviant You should modify Registration.java - specify selenium grid parameters for webdriver or firefox instances you run (see my answer for RemoteWebDriver and DesiredCapabilities). Just by exporting tests from IDE you can't run them with grid. Then on Linux machine you should run your Registration.java with ant for example: http://testng.org/doc/ant.html

Comment: Awesome, I'll give that a shot,  BIG thanks! Also, are you familiar with the TestNG Eclipse plugin? If so, once I have the grid up and running can I straight up deploy from within Eclipse by running it as a TestNG test?

Comment: @btdeviant yes, you can: http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html. In this case you should specify correct grid address: `WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://seleniumgrid:4444/wd/hub"), capability);`

Comment: When I add the provided bit of code to my script, I'm getting an error in Eclipse: RemoteWebDriver cannot be resolved to a type. Is this an issue with my java library?

Comment: Also, it should be noted that I have completely abandoned JUnit in favor of TestNG.

Comment: @btdeviant yes, sorry, this was for c#, for java use `WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();` (http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#selenium-webdriver-s-drivers). Btw, there are a lot of materials as well as sample projects for webdriver and testng, so you could just google for it :)

Comment: I'm definitely checking google prior to coming here. A consequence of my noob-ness is that my terminology is so poor I have no idea why or what these errors are, or why I'm seeing them, or what to search for. I've tried just google the first line of the error straight up to no avail. 

I'm teaching myself everything from the ground up. And by everything, I mean -everything-. I can't begin to tell you how much I appreciate your help.

Comment: Okay. You'll be happy to know that I've done it. Couldn't have done it without you, good sir!

I took your advice. I simply copied an example project for google, transplanted some of the lines from the file that I exported from the Selenium IDE (not a very good method, BTW. Not gonna be doing that again). I also created a superclass to replace the SeleniumTestNGHelper / SeleniumTestCase / SeleniumTestBase class, as that seemed to be causing a lot of problems for me. 

Again, many many many thanks!!